# Visual Studio Code JavaScript Intellisense not working for objects properties

Tags: javascript, ide, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I'm using Visual Studio Code 1.11.1.

For the following code, Intellisense works correctly, understanding that the *canvas* variable is of type *HTMLCanvasElement*:

```
var canvas = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0];
```

In fact, when I write the name of that variable followed by a dot it shows me all properties and methods of *HTMLCanvasElement*.

However, using the following code, in which I wrap that variable inside an object (acting as a namespace), Intellisense doesn't understand anymore that the variable is of type *HTMLCanvasElement*:

```
// create a namespace "App"
var App;
App = {};

App.canvas = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas');
```

When I write "*App.canvas*" followed by a dot character, Intellisense doesn't show me all the properties and methods of *HTMLCanvasElement*. In fact, it considers *App.canvas* of type *any*.

I've tried also to use the *@type* annotation like in the following code, but the result is the same:

```
// create a namespace "App"
var App;
App = {};

/** @type {HTMLCanvasElement} */
App.canvas = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0];
```

Is it possible to make Intellisense understand the variable types for properties of objects (like *App.canvas* in my example)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I work on JS/TS support for VSCode. We use the TypeScript project to power both our JS and TS language support, so believe you are running into this bug: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10868

As a workaround, try declaring the type of `canvas` on `App` itself:

```
/** @type {{canvas:HTMLCanvasElement}} */
var App;
App = {};

App.canvas = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0];
```

Using an object literal should also work:

```
var App = { canvas: document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0] }
```

We're looking into improving IntelliSense in these cases

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! The workaround worked perfectly. Good to know that you are working to solve this problem. Anyway, keep up the good work, as Visual Studio Code is a great lightweight code editor to work with JavaScript! :)

Comment: As of today, `var App = { canvas: document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0] }` doesn't seem to work for me... The workaround kinda works, I am using VS Code 1.45.1 on OS X...

Comment: It's been 4 years. When is this going to be fixed??